# MS Graph - Getting App Token (Console Application)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

- **Console Application - C# .Net 4.6**
- **Dedicated Admin user** - I can't have it prompt every time for a login - must run unattended as a native commandline/console application.

I am simply trying to get bearer token to send along with the Graph SDK calls.
**I get a token** **(the same one every time)** but am told it's expired.  Here is the message:

> Access Token Expired, Use Access & Refresh Tokens to Validate

Since this is a console application I do not know how I can **get/keep** the access and refresh tokens to do this.

FYI:  Earlier effort I followed the steps **Getting Access Without a User**: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_v2_service I could not get past the simple Token HTTP request on that page: unauthorized.

**This is my latest effort.  Any help would be welcome:**

```
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;

public static async Task<string> GetTokenForAppAsync()
{
    if (TokenForApplication == null || TokenForApplicationExpiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))
    {
        TokenCacheUser = null;
        TokenCacheApplication = null;

        ConfidentialClientApplication cl = new ConfidentialClientApplication(Settings.AuthClientId,
            returnUrl,
            new ClientCredential(Settings.AuthClientSecret),
            TokenCacheUser,
            TokenCacheApplication);

        AuthenticationResult authResult = cl.AcquireTokenForClientAsync(new string[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }, true).Result;
        TokenForApplication = authResult.AccessToken;
        Console.WriteLine(authResult.AccessToken);
    }
    return TokenForApplication;
}
```

I am open to any solutions which utilize the MS Graph and Identity Libs.

Comment: Did you found a solution for this question?

Comment: I did, I will see if I can post some code in a  bit..

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/5876732/niels - see answer below, hope it helps and thanks for reminding to follow up on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### graph_authentication_example

This is an example of token based authentication for a console application.  The application must be run at least one time at which you will be prompted to signin but once that is complete an authentication token is stored on the machine the application runs from.

I run a console application as a task from our server and access the Graph API to get various ActiveDirectory data sets using the Graph Endpoints - Typically I need to login once published and then it runs afterwards - this is in the testing phase just now but seems to work well.

#### Dependencies:

- Must have an Azure Active Directory user which will be used for the login and subsequent authentication.  Everything happens in the context of this user.
- The following Nuget packages are used:

  - Microsoft.Graph >= v1.6.2
  - Microsoft.Graph.Core >= v1.6.2
  - Microsoft.Identity.Client >= v1.1.0 preview
  - Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory >= v3.17.1
  - Newtonsoft.Json >= v1.0.3
  - System.Net.Http >= v4.3.3
  - System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms >= v4.3.0
  - System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding >= v4.3.0
  - System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives >= v4.3.0
- You must create an application here [https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/] under same user created above, this will give you your client/app id.
- You can see Graph in action here [https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer/] and login with the user created above to test against your own Azure Active Directory.

#### Settings

I used a .ini file for storing settings but the values are valid, comments in .ini style - note that there are {name} style text in certain entries, those are for string replacement.

You will see Settings.SomeName - that maps to the following:

`[Endpoint]
    ; we don't want v1.0 because of our needs but it is valid
GraphVersion = beta   ; v1.0 or beta
    ; Common Graph endpoint - we sub version
    GraphEndpoint = https://graph.microsoft.com/{version}
    [Auth]
    ; authentication uri
    Uri = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token
    ; authority uri
    Authority = https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}
    ; if we need to login or re-login
    RedirectUri = https%3A%2F%2Flogin.microsoftonline.com%2Fcommon%2Foauth2%2Fnativeclient
    ; you may have a GUID style tenant but 'common' worked fine since it auth's back to Azure anyway
    Tenant = common
    ; the scopes we needed with Graph, yours may vary
    Scopes = { User.ReadBasic.All, User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.AccessAsUser.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All, Group.ReadWrite.All }
    ; the id of your azure application  - guid
    ClientId = xxxx###-2##8-4##9-b##1-ec#########8f2
    GrantType = client_credentials`

#### Code Snippets

I tried to include complete functions and indicate separation by indicating which files they come from.  These are the main parts for token authentication - mostly code complete with exception to 'private' code.

**Starting point:** Let's say that in my Program.cs I have a call to the following function, everything flows from here for authentication:

```
// we are just getting a group by id - CreateAuthenticatedClient() is called before every call to Graph
public static async Task<Group> GetGroupAsync(string groupId)
{
    var graphClient = AuthenticationHelper.CreateAuthenticatedClient();

    try
    {
        var group = await graphClient.Groups[groupId].Request().GetAsync();
        if (group == null) return null;
        return group;
    }
    catch (ServiceException e)
    {
        ConsoleHelper.WriteException($"GetGroupAsync.{ServiceErrorString(e)}");
        return null;
    }
}
```

**AuthenticationHelper.cs - complete class**

```
public class AuthenticationHelper
{
    public static string TokenForUser = null;
    public static DateTimeOffset TokenForUserExpiration;

    // this is the 'magic' where we get the user cache
    public static PublicClientApplication IdentityClientApp = new PublicClientApplication(Settings.AuthClientId, Settings.AuthAuthority, TokenCacheHelper.GetUserCache());

    private static GraphServiceClient graphClient = null;

    // Get an access token for the given context and resourceId. An attempt is first made to 
    // acquire the token silently. If that fails, then we try to acquire the token by prompting the user.
    public static GraphServiceClient CreateAuthenticatedClient()
    {
        if (graphClient == null)
        {
            try
            {
                graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(
                    Settings.GraphEndpoint,
                    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
                        async (requestMessage) =>
                        {
                            var token = await GetTokenForUserAsync();
                            requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                            requestMessage.Headers.Add("azure-graph-test", "manage group membership");
                        }));
                return graphClient;
            }

            catch (ServiceException sex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Could not create a graph client service: {sex.Message}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Could not create a graph client: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
        return graphClient;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     get Token for User
    /// </summary>
    public static async Task<string> GetTokenForUserAsync()
    {
        if (TokenForUser == null || TokenForUserExpiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))
        {
            AuthenticationResult authResult;
            try
            {
                authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(Settings.AuthScopes, IdentityClientApp.Users.FirstOrDefault());
                TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (TokenForUser == null || TokenForUserExpiration <= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddMinutes(5))
                {
                    authResult = await IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(Settings.AuthScopes);
                    TokenForUser = authResult.AccessToken;
                    TokenForUserExpiration = authResult.ExpiresOn;
                }
            }
        }

        return TokenForUser;
    }
}
```

**TokenCacheHelper.cs** - this is a microsoft class that is key to getting/setting the token cache

```
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.
// All rights reserved.
// This code is licensed under the MIT License.
// Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
// of this software and associated documentation files(the "Software"), to deal
// in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
// to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and / or sell
// copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
// furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions :
// The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
// all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
// THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
// IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
// FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT.IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
// AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
// LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
// OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
// THE SOFTWARE.

static class TokenCacheHelper
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Get the user token cache
    /// </summary>
    public static TokenCache GetUserCache()
    {
        if (usertokenCache == null)
        {
            usertokenCache = new TokenCache();
            usertokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(BeforeAccessNotification);
            usertokenCache.SetAfterAccess(AfterAccessNotification);
        }
        return usertokenCache;
    }

    static TokenCache usertokenCache;

    /// <summary>
    /// Path to the token cache
    /// </summary>
    public static string CacheFilePath = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location + "msalcache.txt";
    private static readonly object FileLock = new object();

    public static void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        lock (FileLock)
        {
            args.TokenCache.Deserialize(File.Exists(CacheFilePath)
                ? File.ReadAllBytes(CacheFilePath)
                : null);
        }
    }

    public static void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        // if the access operation resulted in a cache update
        if (args.TokenCache.HasStateChanged)
        {
            lock (FileLock)
            {
                // reflect changes in the persistent store
                File.WriteAllBytes(CacheFilePath, args.TokenCache.Serialize());
                // once the write operationtakes place restore the HasStateChanged bit to filse
                args.TokenCache.HasStateChanged = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```